# Razor hide / show div onchange select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC C# Razor, I have done this in PHP and I tried to use my previous code in Jquery (as shown below)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.CurrentStatus').change(function () {
      if(this.value == "Non-Teaching") {
        $('#div-CurrentTDepartment').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentTPostion').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTDepartment').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTPostion').fadeIn('fast');
      }
      else if (this.value == "Teaching") {
        $('#div-CurrentTDepartment').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentTPostion').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTDepartment').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTPostion').fadeOut('fast');
      }
      else {
        $('#div-CurrentTDepartment').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentTPostion').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTDepartment').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#div-CurrentNTPostion').fadeIn('fast');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

and this is my Create code

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList(ViewBag.Statusdll, "Value", "Text"), "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "location = this.value;" })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="div-NTDepartment">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NTDepartment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NTDepartment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="div-NTPosition">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NTPosition, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NTPosition, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="div-TDepartment">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TDepartment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TDepartment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  </div>
</div>
```

The error is - if you select a 'Non-Teaching' on the dropdown, it shows a 404 error of the page '/Employees/Non-Teaching', which is really a 404 error because I don't have any page like that.

It should only hide or show the divs in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have add the event `onchange = "location = this.value;` which is effectively `window.location.href = TheValueOfYourSelectedOption` when an option is selected.

Remove that from the attributes your adding to `@Html.DropDownList()` and instead use

```
$('#Status').change(function () {
  ....
```

or if this is applicable to multiple controls, add a class name

```
@Html.DropDownList( ...., new { @class = "form-control", @class = "CurrentStatus" })
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the 'location' and the id on the script